# Looking for some options for working with multiple VPNs and switching back and forth between them frequently in the course of a day

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines

I'm a consultant, and I have multiple clients where I connect through their VPN to virtual machines on their network. Each client may have a different VPN setup (cisco, GlobalProtect, etc). In the course of a day I will bounce back and forth between each client's network constantly doing little tasks for them as needed. My client list is growing, and it is becoming maddening to go back and forth. Disconnect current VPN, connect to other vpn, remote in to the vm, and repeat all day long.

Are there any good options to improve my workflow, and my ability to handle more clients? Ideally I would prefer free options, but if there are any great options that are not free I'd love to hear about those as well.

I'm using a windows 10 Pro laptop, and remoting to windows VMs.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things I do as a freelance consultant:

1. If your clients approve, use a remote control solution that doesn't require VPN connectivity, such as TeamViewer, LogMeIn, etc.
2. If you have the resources, build yourself a dedicated virtual machine for each client using VMware Workstation or the like. Granted, this doesn't scale well past a few clients but I do this with the clients I work most frequently with.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - I have been there as well. You cannot have more than one VPN I think in the same time. The routing table will get messy and that depends on configuration of VPN server itself. Is that full or split tunnel, which network CIDR the customer use, etc.

From the IT Managment software ConnectWise is not bad as you pay monthly.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I am trying to setup a VM as a router to store all the different Client VPN's. The plan is to only connect to one VPN at a time. I set this VM with a NAT adapter to connect to the internet and a HOST Only adapter to accept traffic from another VM.
Does this seem reasonable or am I missing something?
Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/534323)